# Get class mapped by @ORM\OneToOne

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, listener

I have following class with mapped property (OneToOne) to another class:

```
class UserProfile
{
 ...
     /**
 * @Verzeilberg\UploadField(mapping="profile_image")
 * @Assert\Type(type="verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Entity\Image")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
protected $image;

...
}
```

For the Image class (verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Entity\Image) I have a created a listner who does stuff before saving the object into the database.

So when saving the UserProfile class with a image the image listener wil be activated And in this image listener I have to get the UserProfile class.

My question is how do I get the UserProfile class when I am in the Image class.

This is the Iamge listener:

```
class ImageListener
{
protected ImageService $imageService;

public function __construct(
    ImageService $imageService
)
{
    $this->imageService = $imageService;
}

public function prePersistHandler(Image $image, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
{
    $reader = new ImageAnnotationReader();
    $reader->loadMetadataForClass($image);
    $this->processImageBeforeSave($image);
}
```

And this is the ImageAnnotationReader:

```
class ImageAnnotationReader
{

/**
 * @throws ReflectionException
 */
public function loadMetadataForClass($class)
{

    $reader = new AnnotationReader();
    $reflClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
```

And here I need the UserProfile class To get this part (in bold):

@Verzeilberg\UploadField(**mapping="profile_image"**)

Comment: So far you have provided a description, but what is your question?

Comment: How do I get the UserProfile class when I am in the Image Class.

Comment: @VieStart: Make that visible in your question by [edit]ing it. Also perhaps a little fragment of example code that shows the place of collaboration of the two entities. And with due respect: It sounds to me this is standard functionality. Which is good, because there might be a chance you may find existing Q&A material already. Reference it and make visible how this is different.

Comment: changed the post

Comment: do you have the geter for the user in the image class? `$image->getUser()`

Comment: That would be a solution. But the Image class is part of a bundle. So I want to prevent that. 

So that someone can use the bundle without chagning it.